# TYPO3 8.7 Extension - Missing storage page ids

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I have an extension with a plugin. I want the default storagePid for the extension to be whatever it is set as in the "Data set collection" field - to my knowledge this is the standard setup anyway.

My setup.ts and constants.ts do not mention the storagePid anywhere (I read that if it is placed in the setup.ts file it overrides the default storagePid number)

When I run the plugin, the controller calls a repository. The repository makes a query, and I have told it to respect the PID storage:

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(TRUE);
....
```

But when I run it I get the following error.

```
Oops, an error occurred!
Missing storage page ids.
```

As a test, I printed out what the Controller thought the storagePid should be:

```
$configuration = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK);
print( "pluginpid = ".$configuration['persistence']['storagePid']);
```

...which printed out the correct number.
So the controller knows what the storagePid number is, but the repository does not. (and the printout above only works in a controller, doesn't work in a repo)

Does anybody know why my repository doesn't know/use the storagePid that I've set?

Answer (score 1):

In constants.ts add `persistence` section, so it will be available trough constants editor of Template module. i.e.:

```
plugin.tx_yourextension_yourplugin {
    view {
        # cat=plugin.tx_yourextension_yourplugin/file; type=string; label=Path to template root (FE)
        templateRootPath = EXT:yourextension/Resources/Private/Templates/
        # cat=plugin.tx_yourextension_yourplugin/file; type=string; label=Path to template partials (FE)
        partialRootPath = EXT:yourextension/Resources/Private/Partials/
        # cat=plugin.tx_yourextension_yourplugin/file; type=string; label=Path to template layouts (FE)
        layoutRootPath = EXT:yourextension/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }
    persistence {
        # cat=plugin.tx_yourextension_yourplugin//a; type=string; label=Default storage PID
        storagePid =
    }
}
```

later in your setup.ts *rewrite* it by:

```
plugin.tx_yourextension_yourplugin {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:{extension.shortExtensionKey}/Resources/Private/Templates/
        templateRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_yourextension_yourplugin.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:yourextension/Resources/Private/Partials/
        partialRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_yourextension_yourplugin.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:tx_yourextension/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        layoutRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_yourextension_yourplugin.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_yourextension_yourplugin.persistence.storagePid}
        #recursive = 1
    }
   
}
```

Tip ZERO: Always clear cache several times ;)

Tip 1: When using Extension Builder for bootstraping your new ext it should add proper *constants* and *setup* files if you added a FE plugin in it.

Tip 2: instead of `print()`it's better to use

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($debuggedData, 'Title');
```

of course, you can import it in your controller

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. In this instance I don't want to use the constants editor to give the Storage Pid, I want to use the "Data set collection" field - the selection box that comes under the "Plugin" tab.   Adding " psersistence.storagePid < " in the setup.ts file  usually ensures the storagePId will be sent through all the way to the repository so if setRespectStoragePage is set to true it will use the correct storagePid. But for some reason, unlike all my other extensions, it isn't working for this one.

Comment: You wrote in a comment that `psersistence.storagePid <` doesn't work. Check double if you didn't make the same typo in your setup.ts. Of course, you don't need to use constants.ts in this case if you don't want, just add to your setup something like `plugin.tx_yourextension_yourplugin.persistence.storagePid = 123`

Comment: Thanks, I checked this and I haven't made that error.